# onclick show div and after some seconds hide my shown div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need some help with my button. i want when i click on the button (click me) the hidden div should be display but after some seconds my hidden div hide automatically. Thanks !!

Here the code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .show {
         -o-transition: opacity 3s;
         -moz-transition: opacity 3s;
         -webkit-transition: opacity 3s;
         transition: opacity 3s;
      opacity:1;
    }
    .hide{  opacity:0; }
  </style>
  <script>
    function ShowSecond()
    {
      var div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
      div2.className="show";
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1" class="show">
  First Div
  <button onclick="ShowSecond()">clickMe</button>
  </div>
  <div id="div2" class="hide">
    Hidden Div
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As my ans is same so only adding demo link. http://jsfiddle.net/k2Ggx/1/

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `setTimeout` function for this:

`setTimeout(function() {
 // your code here
}, 1000);`

This will execute the function after 1 second.

If you want to use jQuery, you can use the `.delay()` function for this:
`$(element).show().delay(1000).hide();`

More info:
https://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 2):

In your `ShowSecond` function do the following

```
 function ShowSecond()
 {
     var div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
     div2.className="show";
     setTimeout(function() {
        div2.className="hide";
     }, 3000);
 }
```

By above code your `div` will hide after `3s`. time is your choice increase or decrease as your requirement

Comment: Thank you so much Blu Angel it works for me perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You want the setTimeout() function

```
setTimeout(function() {
  // Do something after 5 seconds
}, 5000);
```

Comment: setTimeout is just plain JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [**`setTimeout`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) to perform time-delay operations.

```
function ShowSecond() {
    var div2 = document.getElementById("div2");
    div2.className = "show";
    var timeOut = setTimeout(function () {
        div2.className = "hide";
    }, 2000);
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/Dxdh4/1/)

*reason why I used `setTimeout(..)` to a variable `timeOut`:* In future you may need to cancel this timeout operation, which can be done as [clearTimeout(timeOut)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearTimeout)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use CSS3 `animation` instead of `transition`:
<kbd>[running demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AndreaLigios/2hf7b/)</kbd>

HTML

```
<button onclick="animate()">clickMe</button>
<div id="hiddenDiv1" class="hideOnStart">
    Hidden Div
</div>
```

JS

```
function animate() {
    var s = document.getElementById("hiddenDiv1").style;
    s.animationName = 'showAndHide';
    s.animationDuration = '3s';
}
```

CSS

```
@keyframes showAndHide {
      0% { opacity: 0; }
     50% { opacity: 1; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }    
}

.hideOnStart{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Obviously it needs to be prefixed to be cross browser, and the plain JavaScript is just to stick to your code, using jQuery will take care of this things automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap css and want plain javascript to invoke this event then you can use function below:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    if (evt.target.className === 'YOUR_CLASS_NAME') {
        var div2 = document.getElementById("ID_FOR_DIV");
        div2.className = "d-block";
        setTimeout(function() {
         div2.className="d-none";
        }, 6000);
    }
}, false);
```

Or if you are not using bootstrap then you can use

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
    if (evt.target.className === 'YOUR_CLASS_NAME') {
        var div2 = document.getElementById("ID_FOR_DIV");
        div2.style.display= 'block';
        setTimeout(function() {
         div2.style.display = 'none';
        }, 6000);
    }
}, false);
```